# About increment operation in cpp

Tags: c++

are following code samples equivalent?

This:

```
while (true)
    if (!a[counter] || !b[counter++]) break;
```

and this:

```
while (true){
    if (!a[counter] || !b[counter]) break;
    counter++;
}
```

i mean, would increment be performed after all conditions' checking done?

---

Here:

```
int _strCmp(char* s1,char*s2)
{
    int counter = 0;

    while (s1[counter]==s2[counter])
        if (!s1[counter] || !s2[counter++]) return 0;

    if (s1[counter] > s2[counter])
        return 1;
    if (s1[counter] < s2[counter])
        return-1;

    return 0;
}
```

Are there some cases, when this function doesnt work correctly?

Answer (score 4):

No they are not.
Here if !a[counter] returns true the OR'ed condition will not be evaluated.
The second condition in OR is only evaluated if the first condition is false. This is because anything OR'ed with true will be true.

Look at the following image :
[image]

As in the image you can see that case 2 is not equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Since the it is incremented post-evaluation (rather than `++counter`), the value that will be returned is the value before it is incremented. So, those are equivalent statements.

If `counter = 6`, then `!b[counter++]` will return `b[6]`, and then increment `6` to `7`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it yourself changing your code to this:

```
run = 5;

while (run > 0) {
 run--;
 if (!a[counterA] || !b[counterA++]) break;
}

run = 5;

while (run > 0){
 run--;
 if (!a[counterB] || !b[counterB]) break;
 counter++;
}

// compare counterA and counterB
```

EDIT:

Regarding "i mean, would increment be performed after all conditions' checking done?"

No. There are post and preincrement operations. Since you are doing a postincrementation your value would be incremented after it's value was used to evaluate the expression.

Comment: "Try it yourself" is not always a good idea. What if the order in which the sides of || are evaluated are different between compilers? They're not (for bools), but that's an arbitrary design decision by the language designers.

Comment: @NeilKirk That's correct. However in this case he specified c++, not algorithm as tag. I'm certain they won't change the way post/pre evaluation works in c++ anytime soon. Hence just trying it would be a valid method to figure it out